# Why is my fadeslideshow not showing in IE8?

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping someone can help me with this fadeslideshow script. There are many topics from other forums with answers as to why this isn't working of other people but I've tried all their fixes and mine is still not working.

I have no trailing commas, my images on not on my local drive and I have located the proper js file and code. However through this all I have not been able to find out why it is not working in ONLY IE8. It works in ALL the other browsers except this one.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/fadeslideshow.js">


/***********************************************
* Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
   wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
   dimensions: [934, 369], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
   imagearray: [
      ["images/banner-home1.jpg"],
      ["images/banner-home2.jpg"],
      ["images/banner-home3.jpg"],
      ["images/banner-home4.jpg"],
      ["images/banner-home5.jpg"]
],
   displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
   persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
   fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
   descreveal: "ondemand"
})
</script>
```

And this is what I'm calling in my HTML

```
    <div id="fadeshow1"></div>
```

If anyone can give me advice or ideas as to why this might be happening in IE8 I would appreciate it!

Comment: And why would anyone use IE8?

Comment: I had similar problems with IE 7 and 8, was resolved by upgrading to jQuery 1.7.1. The version you are using (1.3.2) is almost 2 years old.

Comment: @blazingkin what a useless comment. How about someone who has Windows XP and can not upgrade to IE9? It's not for us to tell the user what browsers they can / can not use

Comment: Can you make something that works in jsFiddle or post a link to a page you have this ine?  Then, we could actually investigate the errors in IE8 and/or step through it ourselves.

Comment: @DJPTM if there is an issue with a browser then people should not use it... just saying... I know that there are preferences and stuff, but there are plenty of other options available.

Comment: To instruct search engines not to index your page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex.

Comment: I've done the no indexing before but once I take it off google will index anything on the web with that specific keyword. I've had major problems with google doing this in the fast with posts I can't delete.

Comment: So I updated the version of jQuery and it helped me in IE8 but then breaks in Chrome for Windows. Why might it break in Chrome? (I'm on a MAC and testing with Adobe BrowserLab). So I reverted it back to the lower version and will hand out the link in a way google cant pick it up hopefully.

wwwdotsummerlandpropaintingdotcom

I've placed it all together as google can still pick up the keywords, but just written the address out in full. Replace the "dot" with a "d" and thats the site.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Green Day is right.Change the jquery version to newer version.this will solve your issue.earlier i had same issue.i solved it by changing the version.